# Facebook ads app installation tracking in ionic project

Tags: facebook, cordova, ionic-framework, tracking, ads

I'm creating a hybrid mobile app with ionic v1 framework. I'm using "cordova-plugin-facebook4" plugin for facebook integration. Also I want to integrate app installation tracking from facebook ads. Do anyone knows how to enable the app installation tracking with "cordova-plugin-facebook4" plugin? Is there anyway that we can run it in test mode?